# What is the difference between the use of entity and expando?

Tags: java, liferay

I am aware of the fact that expando creates tables virtually and entity originally creates table in database. Both are used to create tables ..therefore I want to know when to use expando and when to use entity? I don't get enough documentation which can explain it on the official site.Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to expand some liferay tables, use expando for example : adding a new column(Custom fields) to User, Blogs, MB, JournalArticle etc, which will not add a column actually in existing table else it will create those columns in ExpandoColumn with referenced table.

Entity must be used, when you want to create a new/custom table.

so simply created expandos when you want to extend Liferay tables, use Entity when you want to create new/custom table for your application.